Reroute all wireguard traffic to other peer
Let's say I have 3 wireguard peers: my PC, a VPS server which I have full access to, and a VPN server, for which I don't. What I'm trying to achieve is to route all my traffic from PC through VPS and then through VPN server. VPS server itself shouldn't route traffic through VPN, of course.
I have read this guide - https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/06/multi-hop-wireguard/#internet-gateway-as-a-spoke. Did everything as described in, except I cannot configure peer C, VPN server in my case. It doesn't work. When enabled, I have no access to the internet nor wireguard's network (10.0.0.*).
Here's my config on VPS server:
[Interface]
Address = 10.68.200.191/32,10.0.0.1/32
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <KEY>

Table = 123
PreUp = ip rule add iif wg1 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del iif wg1 table 123 priority 456

[Peer]
PublicKey = <KEY>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <KEY>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <VPN_ADDR>:51820

So, is there any way to achieve what I want without access to the last peer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Routing is configured separately in each direction, so "have no access" won't tell you which direction needs to be fixed first – instead install tcpdump on the VPS, run a packet capture (e.g. tcpdump -n -i wg0) to see whether your configuration isn't sending packets to the VPN server or just not receiving replies from it.

@grawity From tcpdump output I see logs like "10.0.0.2 > 1.1.1.1", where "10.0.0.2" is my PC and "1.1.1.1" is destination which I try to access from it (without any success). IP of VPN has never appeared. Does it mean I configured something totally wrong?

Are your two connections (PC--VPS and VPS--VPN) using two WireGuard interfaces or only a single interface? If they use separate interfaces, do you see the same 10.0.0.2 > source address when capturing on both?

@grawity I'm not able to capture traffic on VPN server - I only have wireguard credentials to connect to it. I have a "wg0" interface defined on VPS and similar on PC; just did everything as desribed in the guide.

The VPN server expects the client to have a specific IP address (10.68.200.191). Its own WireGuard configuration won't accept traffic coming from other addresses (such as 10.0.0.2), and even if it did, the server wouldn't have a route back to those arbitrary addresses.
So for this to work, your VPS must NAT (SNAT or MASQUERADE) all traffic going to that peer, i.e. rewrite all traffic so that it appears as if coming from the VPS's own address (the 10.68.200.191).
Currently you're adding an iptables MASQUERADE rule that only matches packets going out through -o eth0 – which is what you'd use if the VPS itself were a VPN server for Internet access – but that's not where packets are going in your case; instead the traffic is going back through the same wg1, so that's what the MASQUERADE rule needs to match instead.
When both the client and the VPN server are connected through same interface, the rule should probably be narrowed down to also match the source IP address, i.e. -s 10.0.0.2/32, in addition to the -o wg1. But since the peers represent two completely distinct networks, I would really recommend using two separate interfaces and routing between them instead...
Additionally, when the interface has multiple IP addresses, MASQUERADE may not always pick the correct one automatically. Again, this would be best solved by using two separate WireGuard interfaces to represent your connections to the two networks – but if you insist on using a single interface, then replacing MASQUERADE with SNAT would let you specify the desired address with --to-source. See the 'man iptables-extensions' docs.
(Aside from that, both actions do the exact same thing; MASQUERADE is just automatic SNAT.)
